# Maintenance plan in AWS MSSQL 2017 RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, database-administration

We recently migrated from MSSQL 2017 on-prim to AWS MSSQL 2017 RDS, so earlier we were using MSSQL Maintenance  plan wizard to create plans for `DBCC checkDB, updatestate, Rebuild critical indexes` etc.

But in RDS I dont see this option Maintenance Plan. My question is how we can achieve this in MSSQL 2017 RDS. One option is to write `scripts` and scheduled them in as a SQL jobs.

Any recommendations on this would be highly appreciated

Comment: off-topic - belongs on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) which you should know because you **tagged** database adminstration

Answer (score 3):

```
create procedure dbo.sp_updstats
with execute as 'dbo'
as
exec sp_updatestats
go

grant execute on dbo.sp_updstats to [admin]
go

exec dbo.sp_updstats
```

and using the following scripts I was able to configure all the activities. [Download MaintenanceSolution.sql.](https://ola.hallengren.com/downloads.html)

Be noted: The stored procedure DatabaseBackup is not supported on Amazon RDS. There is a [logic](https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution/blob/master/DatabaseBackup.sql#L442) in [1](https://ola.hallengren.com/downloads.html) solution that checks for it.